# Arithmetic and Geometric Sequences, Requested term

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

c.  Find the first four terms, with a1 as the first term, AND the requested term:
 an= 24 + 5n, a7

d.  Find the first four terms, with a1 as the first term, AND the requested term:
 an= 24 - 9n, a5

If I am given the form of 24+5n, how do I find the first four terms and the requested term? (7th) I need the difference to figure the 7th one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply substitute the value of n into your expression. 
So $a_1 = 24+5 \cdot 1 = 29$ and so on.

Comment: that's what I was thinking originally, I thought there was more to this.

Answer (score 0):

I got

c. a1= 24+5*1=29

a2= 24+5*2=34

a3= 24+5*3=39

a4= 24+5*4=44

a7= 24+5*7=59

d.

a1=24-9(1) = 15

a2=24-9(2) = 6

a3=24-9(3) = -3

a4=24-9(4) = -12

a5=24-9(5) = -21